# Windows 7 Uninstalling Software Fails on Several Computers Consistently

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have several computers that seem to have trouble uninstalling software consistently.  They are Windows 7 machines in an Active Directory domain.  Basically I have been trying to push software updates through SCCM and it has worked on the majority of the computers.  However, these computers consistently fail so I have had to go through and manually uninstall previous versions of software and then install new versions.  To manually uninstall, I've had to use the [Microsoft fix-it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall) to fully uninstall the programs and clean the registry.  Is there a common cause for this to happen consistently on the same computers?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What troubles do you had trying to uninstall these softwares? What software do you trying to uninstall? Do you receive some errors during the uninstallation procedure? The errors are the same on all computers?

Comment: The errors vary but the behavior usually involves a program not showing up in the installed programs, attempting to install the program, and receiving a message that the program is already installed.  I've had this happen for TeamViewer, Chrome, and Acrobat.  and It's all on the same computers. After running the fix-it (which I believe is just fixing up corrupt registry keys) everything seems to work.

Comment: So now your problem is solved?

Comment: No, the issue is I'm trying to find out why this is happening in the first place.  It seems to be consistently happening to the same machines so I need to find out why it's happening so that I don't have to manually go through and do an uninstall and reinstall on each machine every time I have software to update.

Comment: Any error in the event viewer when you install a new software?

Comment: There are no errors in the event viewer...